# I installed Win10 Pro in a vhdx with BitLocker encrypted, how to upgrade OS?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, bitlocker, vhdx

With Windows Update, but it show I can't upgrade, because my C: is encrypted with BitLocker.
Anyother method to upgrade OS?

Comment: Encryption is not a problem. I'm supporting 800 computers right now that are ALL bitlocker encrypted and which install the major Windows Feature Updates and all other upgrades just fine. Even Win7 to Win10 upgrades a couple years ago worked fine. Encryption is not your problem, so please give use more details.

Comment: You can do one of two things.  Suspend BitLocker and upgrade to what I presume is 1803 allowing you to avoid doing so in the future or turn off BitLocker and perform the upgrade then after completion enable it again